# Node-GYP failed with exit code: 1

Tags: javascript, usb, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have to use node-usb in electron.atom to use that I am trying to install node-gyp and I am facing a Issue.

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_proces
s.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\name\\
AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Name\Desktop\electron-quick-start
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I found few same tickets on stackoverflow I have tried them all. Still No success.

Has anyone found any solution for this problem.

Comment: I am also doing feasibility for a similar application in which app should be developed using electron framework and app should be able to read files from USB.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you narrow down the possible causes to the failure by following the steps in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569) from `node-gyp`:

```
xcode-select --install # Install Command Line Tools if you haven't already.
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools # Enable command line tools
```

Hope this helps.